# In starting SMathStudio in Ubuntu 18.04 message: System.Exception: List of Available Languages is not loaded

Tags: 18.04

got `SMathStudioDesktop.0_99_6671.Mono.tar.gz`, created `/user/local/SMath` directory extracted in it. Installed `mono-devel` package then tried to start it.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error I got version `SMathStudioDesktop.0_99_6671.Mono.tar.gz` working on Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1 LTS by installing two packages - `mono-runtime` (contains `mono` executable)  and `mono-devel` (as you already did):

```
sudo apt install mono-runtime mono-devel
```

Then launch `./smathstudio_desktop_mono` executable, it works:

[image: SMath Studio Mono on Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1 LTS]

Note 1: this version is currently stored on this [Slackware mirror](http://ponce.cc/slackware/sources/repo/) and in [ArchLinux](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/smath/). So we can consider it as stable.

Note 2: if you are using default GNOME Shell, then you can try to use previous version - [`SMathStudioDesktop.0_98_5997.Mono.tar.gz`](https://ru.smath.info/file/85RhM).

Note 3: to start over remove SMathStudio configuration folder with `rm -rf ~/.config/SMath/`.

---

Other method is to install version for MS Windows (`SMathStudioDesktop.0_99_6839.Setup.msi`) using PlayOnLinux.

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Run PlayOnLinux (*Applications→Games→PlayOnLinux* or `playonlinux`) then:

1. select *Install*
2. click *Install non-listed program*
3. in opened wizard click *Next* twice
4. in *Manual Installation* click *Next*
5. select *Install program in a new virtual drive*, click *Next*
6. enter name for wine virtual drive (for example, `smathstudio`) and click *Next*
7. check *Install some libraries* and click *Next*
8. select 32-bit and click *Next*, wait it to finish
9. scroll *Please make your choice* to check *POL_Install_dotnet20sp2* and click *Next*, wait it to finish
10. in *Please select the install file to run* click *Browse*, select `SMathStudioDesktop.0_99_6839.Setup.msi` and click *Next*, follow SMath's wizard
11. in PlayOnLinux wizard agree with creation of *SMath Studio Desktop.exe* desktop shortcut by selecting it and clicking *Next*
12. then select *I don't want to make another shortcut*
13. enjoy using SMathStudio by starting it from desktop shortcut.

It works great from here (tested on Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1 LTS):

[image: SMath Studio started from Wine using PlayOnLinux]

Comment: Hello NOrbert, indeed note 2 did it. I saw the Lang directory present, which was not the case in the 99 version. Thanks again.

Comment: Great! So you can accept ✅ my answer  and/or vote for it.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the Mono-version did not work for me (Ubuntu 22.04), instead I resorted to this [website](https://www.randomturns.eu/index.php/installing-smath-studio-on-ubuntu-22-04-with-wine-a-free-calculation-tool-alternative-to-libreoffice-calc-mathcad-excel/) where Wine is used to run Windows files and it works very well.

---

This post will be a walk-through on how to install SMATH on Ubuntu  22.04. <sup>[source](https://www.randomturns.eu/index.php/installing-smath-studio-on-ubuntu-22-04-with-wine-a-free-calculation-tool-alternative-to-libreoffice-calc-mathcad-excel/)</sup>

[image]

Engineers often resort to using spreadsheet tools like Excel or  LibreOffice. In many cases they are appropriate to use, but the obvious  disadvantage is that such sheets easily become messy and if no  explanatory efforts are made they are black boxes since you normally don’t see the underlying equations (and even if you did it is not very  practical).

---

Lately I've become more and more inclined towards executing manual calculations rather than using advanced FEA software to solve  engineering problems (structural mechanics). More often than not  seemingly complex problems can be simplified into intuitive analytical  counterparts. As a synergy effect, they become much easier to review and not least to verify the plausibility of the numeric calculation results produced by FEA. In my line of work I've seen many cases of over-usage  of FEM calculations which in the end tends to complicate the reviewing process and adds time to the project execution.

Naturally since I like to do some personal STEM-related projects on a hobby level I often search for nice (free) software for my 2011 Sony  Vaio (effortlessly running Ubuntu 22.04 at the moment). This leads to my mixed success experience in trying to make this work.

First I tried to follow the recommendations stated at the [SMATH website](https://en.smath.com/view/SMathStudio/summary) where Linux users are encouraged to install the "SMath Studio Desktop for Mono" .tar.gz variant which also requires the installation of mono-complete:

[image]

However I never got it to work properly without using superuser  privileges (and you should never run applications using `sudo su` since it will open up you system to all kind of security issues).

That other file is a .msi file which is for Windows, but fortunenately  there is a way of running Windows programs (.exe & .msi) in Linux  with a fantastic application called [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) (stands for Wine Is Not An Emulator). Download the .msi file and it should end up in the `~/Downloads` directory

[image]

#### Install Wine

If you are using Ubuntu 22.04 I think it is already installed, otherwise run the following commands in the terminal.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wine32
```

After Wine has been installed you can check with `ls -a` if the .wine directory has been created. Then the handy [winetricks](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks) application can be installed.

```
cd "${HOME}/Downloads"
wget  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
chmod +x winetricks
```

It is recommended to create a directory for each application for  various reasons, so either you can use the .wine directory or create a  new 32-bit Windows-directory called .wine_SMATH (the dot makes it hidden, but this is not necessary).

```
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine_SMATH winecfg
```

winecfg creates a configuration file and the winecfg-window  opens and the Windows version can be selected, in this example Windows  10 was chosen.

[image]

In case several prefixes (Windows directories) are created it is  necessary to map the prefix of interest (default directory = .wine):

```
export WINEPREFIX=~/.wine_SMATH/
wine winecfg
```

Once again the winecfg opens and once again the Windows 10 OS is  chosen. In order to verify that the wine_SMATH directory is the default type:

```
winetricks
```

and in the "What do you want to do?" console click the radio button  "Select the default wineprefix". Then please read on the top of the  console. It should read the prefix of choice. From here a variety of  settings and installments can be handled through a GUI, but in this case  we will proceed with terminal commands in order to be streamlined.

[image]

#### Install packages that are required by SMATH Studio

During the course of the many, many, many unsuccessful attempts to  install SMATH on Ubuntu I learned through debugging that some obscure  font was missing – apparently this is a big deal for most of the Windows applications, and also that SMATH requires the .NET Framework 2.0 or later, so in this case I went on to install .NET Framework 3.5 +  Service Pack 1 + allfonts. It is probably overkill with the allfonts,  but I don't have the time or energy to pinpoint exactly what fonts are required.

```
env WINEPREFIX=~/.wine_SMATH winetricks dotnet35 dotnet35sp1 allfonts
```

The terminal will throw some errors regarding the Z-disk but it is  nothing to worry about, the process should run anyhow. Navigate through  the .NET setup window and wait until the installation is complete (the  blue ribbon is 100% built) and press *Exit* when done. The service pack  will then be installed with the same procedure.

[image]

Even though it says *Download complete…* do not cancel the process. (Been there, done that).

When the window for restart shows up *Restart later* can be chosen without adverse consequences.

[image]

When .NET is installed the fonts will be installed followed by a  bunch of warning messages (if installation of fonts is made through  the terminal those warnings will not trigger a user input required  event, but if the installation of fonts was made though the winetricks  GUI just keep on clicking *OK*).

#### Install SMATH Studio .msi

Finally, navigate to the `~/Downloads` directory where the .msi file  should reside and enter the following command in order to install SMATH  in the chosen wineprefix

```
wine start SMathStudioDesktop.1_0_8151.Setup.msi
```

Follow the steps presented by the SMATH Studio installer. In my case I ticked in:

- Install SMATH Studio for "only me" (It should also work for "everyone", but I haven't tried it.)
- Create shortcuts Desktop.
- Accept the suggestion for "Folder".
- Install.
- Launch SMATH Studio.
- "Finish".

If everything went as it should the SMATH Studio application should be running.

[image]